# What is the difference between concept class and hypothesis

Tags: machine-learning

Formal definition that I have seen of concept class is

> class of all true functions

mathematically :

$f:X \rightarrow\{0,1\}$

and that of hypothesis is:

$h:X \rightarrow\{0,1\}$

But most of the times they are used together. For example in definition of PAC

> A concept class  is PAC learnable by a learner  using hypothesis space  if for all concepts ∈, distributions over , true error probability 0≤≤1/2, failure probability 0≤≤1/2, learner  outputs a hypothesis ℎ∈ such that
>
> True error less than or equal to
>
> Computational time is polynomial in 1/,1/, representation size of data object, and representation size of concept

What is the difference?

Comment: take a look at [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/23613/28175)

Answer (score 4):

A concept class ***C*** is a set of true functions *f*. Hypothesis class ***H*** is the set of candidates to formulate as the final output of a learning algorithm to well approximate the true function *f*. Hypothesis class ***H*** is chosen before seeing the data (training process). ***C*** and ***H*** can be either same or not and we can treat them independently.

Answer (score 2):

If one requires that $H = C$, then this is called the "proper PAC" framework compared to "PAC prediction" where we don't care about the representation of $h$ as long as the prediction error is small enough (i.e. we allow $H$ to be the class of all time-polynomial programs).

You can think of a concept as the set of inputs that produce the same label (e.g. all the images that show a chair form the concept "chair" or all the points in the same half space form the concept "true/false").